#  how can I disable links while animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 links and every link do some animation

```
    $("a#home_hits").click(function () {    
    $(".hits").animate({left: "549px", opacity: 1}, { duration: 1500, queue: false });  
});

    $("a#home_hits1").click(function () {   
        $(".hits1").animate({left: "549px", opacity: 1}, { duration: 1500, queue: false });
    });

    $("a#home_hits2").click(function () {
        $(".hits2").animate({left: "549px", opacity: 1}, { duration: 1500, queue: false });
    });
```

but the problem is if I click on any link the other links still working

I tried this code with no luck

```
$('a').click(function () {
if ($('div:animated')) {
    return false;
}
```

});

what can I do to disable the other links while animation is done

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can easily disable your links while animation is running

```
$('a').click(function () {
    if ($(':animated').length) {
    return false;
 }    
});
```

You can of course replace the $('a') selector to match only some of the links.

Answer (score 0):

`$('div:animated')` doesn't return null, but rather a jquery object with 0 elements.  You can use `$('div:animated').length > 0` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement:

```
if ($('div:animated')) {
```

isn't doing what you think, because `$('div:animated')` always returns an object *even when no elements matched the selector* and any object is going to be truthy as far as the if is concerned. You need to test the `.length` property to see if any elements matched:

```
if ($('div:animated').length > 0) {
```

Note: given the relationship between the ids in your anchor elements and the class names in the elements you want to animate you can setup all three animations with a single function.

EDIT: you can use this to set a flag as to whether there's an animation currently running:

```
var animationInProgress = false;

$('a[id^="home_hits"]').click(function () {
    if (animationInProgress)
        return false;
    animationInProgress = true;
    $(this.id.split("_")[1]).animate({left: "549px", opacity: 1},
                                     { duration: 1500, queue: false,
                                       complete : function() {
                                            animationInProgress = false;
                                       } });
});
```

(That uses the [`^=` starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to put a click handler on all the anchors at once, then inside the function uses the part of the id after the underscore as the classname to animate.)

EDIT: To fit with your existing code, you are already returning false from your `$("a").click()` handler, but although that will cancel the default behaviour and prevent the event bubbling up through the DOM it will not prevent other event handlers on the `a` elements from running. To do that use [`stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/):

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
   if ($(':animated').length > 0) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: still the same problem but I think it's my fault. let me show you the whole function
`window.onload = (function(){try{
$('a').click(function () {
if ($(':animated').length > 0) {
return false;
}
});
$("a#home_hits").click(function () { 
$(".block1").animate({left: "549px", opacity: 1}, { duration: 1500, queue: false }); 
});
 
$("a#home_hits1").click(function () { 
$(".block2").animate({left: "549px", opacity: 1}, { duration: 1500, queue: false });
});
$("a#home_hits2").click(function () {
$(".block3").animate({left: "549px", opacity: 1}, { duration: 1500, queue: false });
});
}catch(e){}});`

Comment: I've updated my question with a couple of options. I think the way you are doing it will work if you add `.stopImmediatePropagation()`, though a handler on `$("a")` will stop _all_ links from working so the user won't be able to navigate to other pages in your site until the animation finishes. The other approach is to combine all your `$("a#...")` handlers as shown in my answer and then either use a flag like I've shown or use `if ($(':animated').length > 0) return false;`